# Figuring out the orientation of a dipole and its distance from a point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

The problem assigned is this:

2. A dipole is centered at the origin of a coordinate system, and a small charged sphere is some
   distance away along the perpendicular bisector of the dipole. The particle carries a uniformly
   distributed charge of -3.0 nC , and experiences a 210 nN electric force in the positive y direction.

   a) If the dipole charge is 15 nC and the dipole separation is 20 mm, how far away from the
   dipole is the sphere?

   b) How is the dipole moment oriented?

What I'm confused about is how I would go about figuring out how far away from the dipole the particle is, given only its force in a certain direction, when I don't know how the dipole is oriented, and thus how much of the total force is acting in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charge is on the "perpendicular bisector" of the dipole - that means the diagram looks something like this:

[image]

Can you see it now?

Comment: Well, I know about that, but what if the dipole is not necessarily aligned along on axis, like the question suggests?

Comment: They are asking whether the positive charge is pointing in the positive or negative Y direction. It is aligned but they don't tell you the orientation (polarity).